# memory management in blackberry

Tags: memory-management, blackberry

I want to know how memory is managed in blackberry to execute different applications simultaneously and with the help of which internal file or program or anything.

Answer (score 6):

### Memory Management

It's all about [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) which is a part of OS:

> The BlackBerry® Java® Virtual Machine
>   manages memory usage on the BlackBerry
>   device. The BlackBerry JVM allocates
>   memory, performs garbage collection,
>   and automatically swaps data between
>   SRAM and flash memory. The BlackBerry
>   JVM must also share available memory
>   between the BlackBerry device
>   applications and the BlackBerry® Java
>   Application. The memory capabilities
>   represent the total amount of
>   available memory, which is larger than
>   the available working memory when all
>   of the applications and associated
>   application data exist on the
>   BlackBerry device.

[BlackBerry Java Development Environment - Fundamentals Guide - Memory Management](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5827/Managing_memory_447110_11.jsp)

See also
[SO - BlackBerry memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496113/blackberry-memory-usage)
[SO - Stack size on BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267075/stack-size-on-blackberry)

### Memory usage statistics

You can use Blackberry IDE or BB Eclipse plugin Profiler for profiling
[A50 How to Debug and Optimize](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A50_How_to_Debug_and_Optimize_V2.pdf)

Or BB API for runtime stats:
[net.rim.device.api.system.Memory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html)
[net.rim.device.api.system.MemoryStats](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/MemoryStats.html)

See also
[BlackBerry Support Community Forums - Blackberry Processes](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=21385)